# Java Bukkit coding: cannot kick players

Tags: java, bukkit

**Situation and question:**

I want to kick players when they type swear words (case-insensitive).
Below is my attempt, but it doesn't kick the player. What did I do wrong?
Does not display any errors at all.

**Source code**:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e) {

    Player player = e.getPlayer();

    if (muted.contains(player.getUniqueId())) {

        e.setCancelled(true);
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "[TC]" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You are muted and cannot chat.");

    } else {

        String message = e.getMessage();

        if (message.contains("(?i)fuck") || message.contains("(?i)shit") || message.contains("(?i)ass") || message.contains("(?i)porno") || message.contains("(?i)porn") || message.contains("(?i)crap") || message.contains("(?i)dumb")) {

            player.kickPlayer(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Watch your language, please!");
            e.setCancelled(true);

        }

        message = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('§', message);
        message = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', message);
        String text = ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "[Chat]" + ChatColor.YELLOW + player.getName() + " " + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Says: " + ChatColor.AQUA + message;
        player.playNote(player.getLocation(),Instrument.PIANO, Note.natural(1, Tone.A));

        text.replace("(?i)", "");

        text = text.replace("<3", "❤");
        text = text.replace(":)", "☺");
        text = text.replace(":-)", "☺");
        text = text.replaceAll("(?i)fuck", "****");
        text = text.replaceAll("(?i)ass", "***");
        text = text.replaceAll("(?i)shit", "****");
        text = text.replaceAll("(?i)porno", "*****");
        text = text.replaceAll("(?i)porn", "****");
        text = text.replaceAll("(?i)dumb", "****");
        text = text.replaceAll("(?i)crap", "****");

        e.setFormat(text);
        e.setMessage(text);

    }

}
```

Comment: `.contains` will not match ignoring case, it will match the sequence exactly. Use a `Pattern` or something more versatile for stuff like this.

Comment: Note that you'd kick players that say something innocuous like "grass".

Comment: I have removed the e.setCancelled(true); and it's like... Just it can't pass the event to my class....

Comment: Error in my class: at me.Sculptor86.TinserCraft.Main.onPlayerChat(Main.java:109) ~[?:?]

Comment: Also, I have changed contains into matches.

Comment: And, I also tried removing the chatcolor.

Answer (score -2):

Use [String.matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) to match a regexp. Also, you can add all your swear words to some array/collection and use Java 8 features to simplify your code, e.g.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String message = "hello fuck world ass shit here i am";
    final String[] swearWords = {"ass", "fuck", "shit", "porno", "porn"};
    final boolean hasSwearWords = Stream.of(swearWords).anyMatch(w -> message.matches("(?i).*\\s" + w + "\\s.*"));
    if (hasSwearWords) {
      System.out.printf("Bad user!");
    }
    final String cleanMessage = Stream.of(swearWords).reduce(message,
        (msg, w) -> msg.replaceAll(
            "(?i)(\\s)" + w + "(\\s)",
            "$1" + new String(new char[w.length()]).replace("\0", "*")+ "$2"));
    System.out.println(cleanMessage);
  }
```

Here is the code that doesn't require Java 8:

```
  @EventHandler
  public void onPlayerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e) {
    Player player = e.getPlayer();

    if (muted.contains(player.getUniqueId())) {
      e.setCancelled(true);
      player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "[TC]" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You are muted and cannot chat.");
    } else {
      String message = e.getMessage();
      String[] swearWords = {"fuck", "shit", "ass", "porno", "porn", "crap", "dumb"};

      for (String word : swearWords) {
        if (message.matches("(?i).*\\s" + word + "\\s.*")) {
          player.kickPlayer(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Watch your language, please!");
          e.setCancelled(true);
          break;
        }
      }

      message = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('§', message);
      message = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', message);
      String text =
          ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "[Chat]" + ChatColor.YELLOW + player.getName() + " " + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Says: " +
              ChatColor.AQUA + message;
      player.playNote(player.getLocation(), Instrument.PIANO, Note.natural(1, Tone.A));

      text = text.replace("<3", "❤")
                 .replace(":)", "☺")
                 .replace(":-)", "☺");
      for (String word : swearWords) {
        text = text.replaceAll(
            "(?i)(\\s)" + word + "(\\s)",
            "$1" + new String(new char[word.length()]).replace("\0", "*")+ "$2");
      }

      e.setFormat(text);
      e.setMessage(text);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your filter matches too much. Cl**ass**ic issue.

Comment: Err... I meant cl***ic issue

Comment: @VladimirChampion By regexp I was referring to a pattern with which you can match a String (or part of)  -http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html. The String.contains method does not accept a regexp as an argument which is why it fails to find the words. As I (and others) have said, you have to use String.matches. On the other hand, String.replaceAll accepts a regexp which has to be case-insensitive and match only full words. See the Pattern JavaDoc for more info on how to do this.

Comment: @JanDvorak True, hopefully I have fixed it, please improve the answer further if necessary.